# can't build taco ios BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'xxx.plist'

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

I use visual studio 2015 to build mobile cordova useing remotebuild 
but I got wanrning and error :

```
Warning     PackageApplication is deprecated, use `xcodebuild -exportArchive` instead.  

Error   BLD102  Error : BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'xxx.plist'
```

Comment: Have you tried clear the cordova cache? You can find it under `Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova Cache`.

Comment: yes and it's not working, I finally end with working on xcode and object c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around is to ignore the problem and locate build folder on mac its hold number that shown when you build set it to release and then go to the xcode open project fix errors and test it